# Static variable in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, addresses, mapping

I define a balance as follows :

```
mapping (address => uint[]) Energy_Balance
```

to keep the history of each transaction. I set its new value as follows :

```
First Transaction: balances[owner][0] = balances[owner][0] + value; 
Second Transaction: balances[owner][1] = balances[owner][1] + value;
```

Now, I want to define a `uint` `counter` such that it can keep its **last value every time it is increased one unit** as follows :

```
balances[owner][counter] = balances[owner][counter] + value
```

If I define counter as follows, is it correct in solidity and it can keep its **last value** ?

```
static uint counter = 0;
function myFunction(uint value) {
    balances[owner][counter] = balances[owner][counter] + value;
    counter = counter +1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify.

```
function myFunction(uint value) {
  balances[owner].push(value);
}
```

Also, some useful getters:

```
function getOwnerValueCount(address owner) returns(uint count) {
  return balances[owner].length;
}
```

Add `public` to your mapping for `Energy_Balances` and you will get a "free" getter approximately:

```
function Energy_Balances(address owner, uint row) public view returns(uint) {
  return Energy_Balances[owner][row];
}
```

Aside: It would be more conventional to camelCase `energyBalances`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thankyou. do you mean in case of using "energyBalances[owner].push(value);" I don't need to define energyBalances as an array like this : mapping (address => uint[]) energyBalances ?

Comment: No. Assuming you did. `mapping (address=>uint [])` means there's an array each address. `push` appends another row, so you don't need to manage the counter yourself.